# Pass PartialView with AJAX and still using Controller in MVC on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a div where I want to put a PartialView when I press a input of type submit. The partialview must be created inside the div after the Controlleraction ShowDetail() has executed else I'm getting nullreference at my model. I have made a attempt with AJAX but I'm not really sure how the write this, and especially when the model needs to be created before the partialview is posted into the div. I would really appreciate some guidance or solution

My view (the div that is supposed to keep the partialview is anCalcDetail):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowDetail", "Calculation"))
                    {
                       <div class="calculateBox">
                            <label for="calcOption">Choose value to calculate:</label>
                            <select form="anFormCalcInput" id="calcOption" title="Choose what value you want to calculate">
                                <option value="anPMT">Payment (PMT)</option>
                                <option value="anI">Interest (I)</option>
                                <option value="anFV">Future value (FV)</option>
                                <option value="anPV">Present value (PV)</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="calculateBox" background-color="#777777">
                            @Html.Label("Present value (PV)")
                            @Html.TextBox("PresentValue")
                            @Html.Label("Future value")
                            @Html.TextBox("FutureValue")
                            @Html.Label("Interest rate")
                            @Html.TextBox("InterestRate") <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="advanceOrArrears" id="inAdvance" value="inAdvance" /> In advance<br />
                            <input type="radio" name="advanceOrArrears" id="inArrears" value="inArrears" /> In arrears
                        </div>
                        <div class="calculateBox">
                            <label for="startDate">Start date:</label>
                            <input type="date" id="anStartDate" name="startdate" title="Choose start date for your calculation" /><br />
                            @Html.Label("Payment frequency")
                            <select form="anFormCalcInput" id="anPmtFreq" title="Choose the payment frequency, for example: Every month">
                                <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                                <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
                                <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
                            </select><br /><br />
                            @Html.Label("No of payment periods")
                            @Html.TextBox("PaymentPeriods")
                            @Html.Label("Date time convention")
                            <select form="anFormCalcInput" id="anDTC" title="Choose your Date time convention">
                                <option value="360360">360/360</option>
                                <option value="365365">365/365</option>
                            </select><br /><br />
                            <input type="submit" id="anCalcBtn" class="calcBtn" name="anSubmitBtn" value="Calculate" title="Calculate your calculation" />
                        </div>
                    }
                    </div>
                    <table cellspacing="0" width="80%">
                    <div class="calcDetail" id="anCalcDetail">
                    </div>
```

My partialview:

```
@model IEnumerable<CalcFactory.Models.Calculation>

<table cellspacing="0" width="80%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Invoice amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Interest rate
        </th>
        <th>
            Interest amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Amortization
        </th>
        <th>
            Capital balance
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
    </td>
    <td align="center">
    </td>
    <td align="center" id="startValue">
    </td>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceAmount)
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestRate)
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestAmount)
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amortization)
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresentValue)
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

My controller (which needs to be runned before the partialview is dumped inside the div):

```
public ActionResult ShowDetail(FormCollection form)
    {

        List<Calculation> cList = new List<Calculation>();
        Calculation calc = new Calculation();
        calc.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(form["startdate"]);
        calc.InvoiceAmount = 2000;
        calc.InterestRate = Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]);
        calc.InterestAmount = (Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]) * Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]) / 360 * 30);
        calc.Amortization = (2000 - (Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]) * Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]) / 360 * 30));
        calc.PresentValue = Convert.ToDouble(form["PresentValue"]) - calc.Amortization;
        cList.Add(calc);
        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(form["PaymentPeriods"]); i++)
        {
            Calculation calcBefore = cList.Last();
            calc = new Calculation();
            calc.Date = calcBefore.Date.AddMonths(1);
            calc.InvoiceAmount = 2000;
            calc.InterestRate = Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]);
            calc.InterestAmount = (calcBefore.PresentValue * Convert.ToDouble(form["InterestRate"]) / 360 * 30);
            calc.Amortization = (calc.InvoiceAmount - (calcBefore.PresentValue * calc.InterestRate / 360 * 30));
            calc.PresentValue = calcBefore.PresentValue - calc.Amortization;
            cList.Add(calc);
        }
        return PartialView("ShowDetail", cList);
    }
```

And finally my JS/Attempt for AJAX:

```
$(document).on('click', '#anCalcBtn', function () {
$.post("ShowDetail.cshtml", function (data) {
    //Run the ShowDetail action before the data is posted into the div
    //Post partialview into div-id #anCalcDetail
    $("#anCalcDetail").html(data);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changeing Html.BeginForm to Html.AjaxForm and make UpdateTargetId = "anCalcDetail" it actually worked without the AJAX-call in the .js

Answer (score 1):

resources are not served the way you are doing it right now in mvc. To call your `ShowDetail` method, change your `jQuery post` to this:

```
$('#anCalcBtn').on('click', function (e) {
      var form = $('form');
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({ 
          url: 'Calculation/ShowDetail', 
          type: 'POST', 
          data:form.serialize(), 
          dataType: 'json', 
          contentType: 'application/json', 
          success: function (data) { 
              $("#anCalcDetail").html(data);
     });
});
```

make sure you mark your ActionMethod `HttpPost` i.e.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowDetail(FormCollection form)
{ 
       ///usual code
}
```

Comment: Your code still sends me to a new view, and does not paste the partialview into the div

Comment: ohh, my bad, you have to stop the normal flow of the click before you can make a request. check it out now

Comment: hey, check out my answer, now you are sending all the controls data as the data of the httpResponse

Comment: Feels like it doesn't bother about the ajax and just runs the ShowDetail-action instead

Comment: Is there any way to check so the ajax-post is sending the right code?

Comment: yes, write `debugger` just before the `var form=..` line inside the click event, and goto the browser's console i.e. f12(chrome & ie), shift+f5 (mozilla) and click the button, and debug, also switch to the Networks tab of the debugger console to see wat request was made, or some error occured

Comment: also, try writing `return false` at the end of the click button event handler

Comment: I think the event on buttonclick doesn't execute..Becuase i tried with an alertbox in the beginning (before var form=...) and it didn't showed

Comment: hey, remove the type=`submit` from the button and make it `type=button`

Comment: Doesn't work either. Tried with an alert again and for me it seems like the function isn't execute at all..but there are no problem with linking to the script (tried other functions as well)